# Using trained linear-approximated-value-function in model-free scenario at decision-making stage

Tags: dynamic-programming, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

suppose I successfully trained (by using the process of "approximated value-iteration" or "fitted Q iteration") a linear function that approximate reasonably the value function of some good policy. This "linear value function approximator" is defined by a parameter-vector theta, and it takes as its input a high-level-features vector representing a current "state".

I wonder how can the agent, during the decision-making stage, use this trained linear approximator to choose an action in model-free scenario...? I emphasize that the approximator-function's input is, by definition, only the "state" alone (represented by the feature vector).. The "action" is not part of the input.. (in other words: the approximator is "state-value" function not "state-action-value" function), as the agent operates here in a model-free situation (like, for example, playing a game) the trained-agent can not simply try out all the possible actions from current-state and compute for each one its Q(state, action), and then take the argmax... because once you coose one action you transmitted-thrown to a next state..
It is not clear to me how the underlying "actions" implicitly contained the policy that is defined by the "linear approximator function" could be accessible to the agent to actually make the decisions. any ideas?